# How to sort a list of objects by another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes:

```
class Location
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then I create two lists of objects:

```
        var locations = new List<Location>()
        {
            new Location()
            {
                Address = "AA"
            },
            new Location()
            {
                Address = "BB"
            },
            new Location()
            {
                Address = "CC"
            },
            new Location()
            {
                Address = "BB"
            }
        };

        var people = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person()
            {
                Address = "BB",
                Name = "Foo"
            },
            new Person()
            {
                Address = "CC",
                Name = "Bar"
            },
            new Person()
            {
                Address = "AA",
                Name = "xxx"
            },
            new Person()
            {
                Address = "BB",
                Name = "yyy"
            },
        };
```

What I want is to sort the people list by matching Address property in the locations list. This is the result I would like to have:

```
xxx
Foo
Bar
yyy
```

I tried with this code:

```
var orderedPeopleList = people.OrderBy(p => locations.FindIndex(l => l.Address.Equals(p.Address)));
```

But it is not working correctly and the two last lines are in the wrong order. What is the best way to do this ordering with linq?

Comment: `locations` contains two entries with the same `Address` (`"BB"`)

Comment: How do you differentiate between the people and addresses with "BB"?

Comment: Try sth like this:
`var processed = new List<Int>();
people.OrderBy(p => {
var index = -1;
do {
index = locations.FindIndex(index, l => l.Address.Equals(p.Address));
}while(!processed.Contains(index));
return index;
});`

Comment: What do you do if there is an item in one list but not the other?

Comment: try people.OrderBy(p => locations.Where(l => l.Address == p.Address)
  .First()    
  .Position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var orderedPeopleList = new List<Person>();

foreach (var location in locations)
{
    var foundPeople = people.Where(p => p.Address == location.Address).FirstOrDefault();
    if (foundPeople != null)
    {
        orderedPeopleList.Add(foundPeople);
        people.Remove(foundPeople);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do it :

```
  locations= locations.OrderBy(x => x.Address).ToList();
  var orderedPeopleList=new List<Person>();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.Count(); i++)
  {
        peopelOrderedList.Add(people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address == locations[i].Address && peopelOrderedList.All(c => c.Name != x.Name)));
  }

  peopelOrderedList.RemoveAll(x => x == null);
```